# Separate the name of a property from its value when the name and value have '=' signs in them

Tags: regex, sed

I am struggling with a problem that I am trying to solve with sed or any other *nix command line.

I am trying to separate the name of a property from its value in a property file.

The problem is that some property names and property values have the '=' sign in them.

```
(Y\ \=\ Generate\ Notification\ Letter)=(Y \= Generate Notification Letter)
(Y\ \=\ Generate\ Restriction)=(Y \= Generate Restriction)
(Y\ \=\ Sort\ by\ Group\ ID)=(Y \= Sort by Group ID)
```

I can't use cut with a '=' delimiter like I would normally do.

How do I make a regular expression that separates everything before the non-escaped '=' sign and everything after the non-escaped '=' sign?

Is there another way to do it other than sed?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Output 1 is the property name, output 2 is the property value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would replace the un-escaped `=` with a tab character.

```
sed 's/\([^\\]\|^\)=/\1\t/g' file
```

You could try this also. I assumed that each line in your input file has a single unescaped `=` character.

```
$ sed 's/\(.*[^\\]\|^\)=\(.*\)/Name: \1\t Value: \2/g' file
Name: (Y\ \=\ Generate\ Notification\ Letter)    Value: (Y \= Generate Notification Letter)
Name: (Y\ \=\ Generate\ Restriction)     Value: (Y \= Generate Restriction)
Name: (Y\ \=\ Sort\ by\ Group\ ID)   Value: (Y \= Sort by Group ID)
```

Comment: That assumption is correct, the input would have only one non-escaped `=` character.
  
It could have multiple `\=`.